# Unable to retrieve workflow rule from case comment object

Tags: community, salesforcedx, workflow, vs-code, case-comment

I have created a new workflow rule for Case Comment object. When trying to retrieve from org browser getting this error

> "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

and when i tried to retrieve via git command `"sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Case_Comment__c"` getting this message

> === Retrieved Source No results found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

I created dummy workflow with the same name (CaseComment.Workflow-meta.xml) and retrieved source from org. It got updated with new values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you made a custom object called Case Comment, Case Comment is a standard object with the API Name `CaseComment`. So the command you're looking for is:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:CaseComment
```

Comment: Yes i tried, but i couldnt get the workflows from the case comment, other fields and custom objects were retrieved. Any help on workflows?

Comment: Workflows are a different Metadata type, so you need `Workflow:CaseComment`. [Here's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm) a list of all supported Metadata types for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the source code by using the workbench, unzip the retrieved file into your local drive then launch: sfdx force:mdapi:convert --rootdir
`<c:\workbench\--->`
you can also try logging  by using `--loglevel LOGLEVEL`
Generally logs gets stored in `$HOME/.sfdx/sfdx.log`